# what ObjectStructure in visitor design pattern is?

Tags: design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have a question about visitor pattern.
What is not clear to me is what is the Object structure shown in the visitor design.
from the GOF design pattern book:

> ObjectStructure:
>
> - can enumerate its elements.
> - ObjectStructure:  may provide a high-level interface to allow the visitor to visit its elements.
> - ...

Does the second ponint mean I can add the accept method to the ObjectStructure class? [like in the code below]

```java
class ObjectStructure{
    private Collection<Element> collection;
    
    public void accept(Visitor visitor){
        for(Element element: collection)
            element.accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

The Object Structure can be any container of elements to be visited. Its purpose is just to iterate over the different elements, so what you have is fine. The elements could also be connected by a tree structure, like the Composite pattern.

A unique feature of the Visitor pattern is that the elements to be visited do not require any common hierarchy beyond a shared `accept()` method. You could visit completely unrelated elements from unconnected sources, with no Object Structure at all (though that probably wouldn't be very useful).

Comment: >The elements could also be connected by a tree structure, like the Composite pattern.  But when you have a tree structure a `accept()` method in the ObjectStructure is useless because given a reference to the root node you can visit all the structure.  In my case I need the collection of elements in the ObjectStructure because these are not linked together like in the composite pattern.  Is what I'm saying right?

Comment: The tree itself is the Object Structure. You could also treat the collection itself as the Object Structure: `collection.forEach(element -> element.accept(visitor))`. You could also wrap the collection in an additional object, as you've shown. The Object Structure simply indicates the client needs access to multiple elements somehow. It doesn't matter how you provide that access. The client could have a method that takes one element at a time with no Object Structure at all.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I think I understand.  My doubt comes from articles i've read: Here [link](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor) (the first UML diagram) is the Client that has to go through the collection in the ObjectStructure. Other articles like here [link](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Visitor/) do as we are saying.

Comment: The difference I see is that in the wikipedia one it's the client that has to "walk" through the collection and call the accept method for each element of the ObjectStructure.  In the second one it's the ObjectStructure that walks through the collection with acceptAll method.  In the second one the only thing client has to do is call the acceptAll whereas in the first one it's required that ObjectStructure collection is exposed to the client (with a getter maybe) in order to call the accept method in every Element.

Comment: That's an implementation detail. The pattern is the same whether the iteration is internal or external to the client. The client is (transitively) coupled to the concrete elements either way, through the Visitor interface. Side note: both internal and external iteration are covered under the Iterator design pattern.